# Spring security with LTPA token

Tags: spring-security, ltpa

we have a web application using Spring Security to do authentication. Now we have a project need to deploy the web application in WebSphere and use LTPA for SSO between other applications.

How can i configure spring security to use WebSphere LTPA authentication?
Once spring security and LTPA have authenticated, how can i set/get the LTPA token in/from cookie?

Thanks in advance.